# how to remove a subview which was released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

A beginner's question: I am trying to remove a subview after having added it to a view and then releasing it, i.e. I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9, i++) {
        UIButton *btn = [indexButtons objectAtIndex:i];
    btn.tag = x;
    [notePage1 addSubview:btn];
    [btn release];

}
```

How can I get rid of one of these btn, e.g. number 0? I thought of

```
UIButton *btn = [indexButtons objectAtIndex:0];
if ([btn isDescendantOfView:notePage1]) { [btn removeFromSuperview]; }
[btn release];
```

But this will simply crash the app. I get no error log at all? - app simply terminates. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't release the button in any of these snippets.  You only use `release` if you have specifically used `retain`, `alloc`, `copy` or `new`.

Your code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9, i++) {
        UIButton *btn = [indexButtons objectAtIndex:i];
    btn.tag = x;
    [notePage1 addSubview:btn];
}
```

and

```
UIButton *btn = [indexButtons objectAtIndex:0];
if ([btn isDescendantOfView:notePage1]) { [btn removeFromSuperview]; }
```

Adding to a to a superview increases the retain count automatically and removing releases automatically.  You don't have to worry about any of it.

Comment: Thanks! Oh dear, I should have known this... thanks for reminding me - hopefully I'll remember this time!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't release the button, because you didn't allocate it.

It's all about object ownership. You should never release an object that you don't own. You can take ownership of an object by sending one of the following messages:

- alloc
- new
- retain
- copy

Comment: Thanks! But otherwise, this would be the way to go about this, right? Or is there are more elegant way?

Comment: It's fine, as long as you don't release objects you didn't allocate

Comment: "nor did you copy or retain it" should be also in the answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

don't release buttons, you never Alloc'ed them